# How do I define routes in play framework2.0 such as {controller}.{action}

Tags: router, playframework-2.0

in play framework 1.0
* /{controller}/{action} {controller}.{action}
how do I define in play2.0

Answer (score 2):

It is similar but it has a little bit different syntax.

```
GET   /clients/:id          controllers.Clients.show(id: Long)
```

Main difference is parameters. In play 1.2.x it was `/clients/{id}` and also note that in action you need to define parameter and unlike Java convention you define type after parameters (Scala style)

For more information please refer: [JavaRouting](http://www.playframework.org/documentation/2.0/JavaRouting)

Comment: when I add a new controller ,I must add a router? In play 1.x,I think convention over configuration is good design,I don't care the route,but in 2.x,it is so difficult

Comment: yes.. you need to create a route when you add a function.. because route is a component that translates your HTTP request to an action call.. but this is same in both play 1.2.x and play 2.0. play2.0 has a different approach so it has both advantages and disadvantages.. it is a real trade-off between simplicity and power..